# How to generate keyboard, mouse event by voice command in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, api, ubuntu, voice-recognition

I have recognised voice commands from pocket-sphinx application, but I do not to implement these commands in Ubuntu. Are there any API in C or C++ (same as robot class in  java) to implement the commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by working with Xserver through [XTest framework](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XTesting/). The API is described at http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/Xext/xtestlib.html, the example is http://bharathisubramanian.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/x11-fake-key-event-generation-using-xtest-ext/. Robot uses XTEst

The second API to use is [AT-SPi](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/At-spi), an accessibility API. It's actually more powerful than just XTEst and allow you to deeply analyze and semantically understand the UI. AT-SPI must be enabled by the user though. As an example you can check [Florence](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html).

Comment: Thank you, that was the stuff I was looking.